I want to connect a headset with kenwood (baofeng) plug to a Yaesu FT-60 HT
The adapter I have keys up instantly when I plug the headset in.
Is there a known adapter or do I need to make one myself?

Please add more information. What is wrong with the adapter you have now? What do you mean by it keys up instantly?

The four connectors on the pin are:


Make sure your plug is TRRS, not TRS - or you'll always be bridging the PTT and ground pins, which triggers PTT.

If you have a TRRS connector (CT-44 or equivalent) there's still an issue with the FT-60, not the adapter.


As you insert the plug, mic/PTT can bridge the mic/PTT and ground contacts of the socket, which momentarily triggers PTT until the plug is fully inserted. Some FT-60 users will wrap the mic cable behind the belt clip or add a rubber band so the radio doesn't accidentally transmit when the plug comes partially out.
https://www.amateurradio.com/yaesu-ft-60-speaker-mic-complaint/
